# php :No node specified thrown in base_facebook.php

Tags: facebook-graph-api, error-handling, facebook-php-sdk, php

hi I am using this code to make api call:

```
function foo(){
   require_once 'facebook.php';
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                      'appId'  => $facebook_appid,
                      'secret' => $facebook_app_secret,
                    ));
   $data=$facebook->api('/me/photos',array('access_token'=>'my_access_token'));
}
```

But now I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: No node specified thrown in C:\Users\xxx\base_facebook.php on line 1106
```

What does it mean? how do i fix it?

Comment: `var_dump($facebook_appid, $facebook_app_secret);` and make sure they contain the values you think they do (I'm guessing they don't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you loggin the facebook app?  [reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/)

```
function foo(){
$config = array(
    'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
 if($user_id) {
      try {
       $data=$facebook->api('/me/photos',array('access_token'=>'my_access_token'));
      }
 } catch(FacebookApiException $e) { }
 }
}
```

You should make sure if user is loggin? else `$facebook->getLoginUrl()`